# Laravel Form Application form <file> field can not find camera photos on android devices

Tags: php, android, forms, file-upload, laravel

Server: Linux
OS: Centos
PHP: 5.4.26
FW: Laravel 4
Test Devices: Samsung Galaxy s2, Samsung Note 8 n5105
Device OS: Android

We have web based mail form app developed with php (Laravel FW). In our application; we have some kind of forms that has form tags like (input, file field, text area).

If we fill fields and attach some files on form and datas embedding in a pdf, this pdf attaching on an e-mail and transporting with swiftmailer to target addresses.

Everything going fine till here.

But if we use our forms via mobile devices (tablets, smartphones etc.);

If we use "file field" on mobile devices; 
First device ask us Which way i want to choose your file (Camera, Gallery, Browser Photos etc.)

If we choose selecting a file directly hdd, or sd card on device evertyhing goings fine. Datas injecting on pdf, and pdf is attaching on email and reaching our email adressess correctly.

But if we use "file field" selecting via camera and take a shot, and add that on our form; datas injecting on pdf without photo.

We think photo is not upcoming server and server cannot injecting it into pdf.

Something wrong with file path. But we cant find any solution.

Any help will appricated.

Comment: How are you converting to PDF?

Comment: We used dompdf class to inject datas into pdf

Comment: My first thought is the image coming right from the camera is probably not being compressed and may be larger than your `max_upload_file_size` setting in your `php.ini` file.  `post_max_size ` may also be having an effect as well.

Comment: I will try to increase it. If it will not help, i will poke you from here :) thanks for advice

Comment: just for clarity, `max_upload_file_size` should be `max_upload_filesize`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was just the default `upload_max_filesize` limit from `php.ini`.